# Regex to match all top-level functions

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'd like to parse PHP code with a regex to find all the top-level functions declared in our codebase.

The simple:

```
^\s*function\s*([\w_-]+)\(
```

works pretty well, but catches the extra

```
class Foo {
  function bar() {...}
}
```

Any ideas on how to skip non-top-level functions that don't have scope delcared?

Note: I know, I know, I should use a real parser but I want something quick and dirty that can run in `grep -R -P` over a very large codebase.

Comment: I don't think this can be done by `grep`, it just looks at each line in isolation, and can't tell that some previous line was a class declaration. You could write something in awk, perl, or php that looks for class declarations and then skips to the end of the class by counting matching braces, although it might get confused by unmatched braces in comments or strings if you're not extremely careful. Why aren't you using an IDE with tools to do this kind of analysis?

Comment: `grep -P` does multiline

Comment: OK, but detecting whether something is inside matched braces is really hard with regex.

Comment: Regexen are probably not the right tools for this job, but have a look at my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

On a well-indented code base,

```
^function\s*([\w_-]+)\(
```

should catch only top-level functions. If you expect leading spaces, you could use a [zero-width negative look-behind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for a `{`, to avoid functions right at the beginning of a class declaration:

```
(?<!{)\s*function\s*([\w_-]+)\(
```

Comment: That's a good start. Is there a way to do that for the second function in the class?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to say that this sort of stuffs depend largely on how disciplined you code is.  For myself, I start all top-level functions immediately at the beginning of lines.  So if I wanted to find non-top-level functions (in vim), I simply do

```
/^[[:space:]]\+function[[:space:]]\+\w\+\>
```

and

```
/^function[[:space:]]\+\w\+\>
```

for all top-level functions.

However, as I said, it depends on how well formatted your codebase is.  Good luck!

Comment: Nope, my codebase is large and sometimes top-level functions are indented and sometimes class functions are not indented at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use ruby (or basically anything with named capture groups), you could use something like this:

```
^\s*(?<type>\w+)\s*(?<name>[\w_-]+)(?<function>\([^()]*\))?\s*(?<body>{((?>[^{}]+)|(\g<body>))*})
```

The ones that are functions will have brackets in the `function` capturing group. The ones are classes won't.

http://rubular.com/r/3dXZts6OYF

Extremely brittle though.